# GetUserAsyn retorna null [net-core Identity]

Tags: mvc, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core, identity

Buenas tengo un proyecto net core mvc, donde utilizo Identity para los usuatios, registro, login, etc.

Mi problema es que al loguearse lo redirecciono al Index de articulo, donde quiero tomar el usuario logueado con `await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User)` y me retorna `null`.

Les muestro parte del código para ver si me pueden ayudar (si necesitan ver más diganme).
El Login y el Registro dentro del LoginController, y el Index del ArticuloController.

**LoginController**

```
public async Task<string> RegisterUser(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            ErrorViewModel message = new ErrorViewModel();

            bool x = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Customer");
            if (!x)
            {
                var role = new IdentityRole
                {
                    Name = "Customer"
                };
                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
            }

            User user = new User
            {
                UserName = model.Email,
                Name = model.Name,
                Surname = model.Surname,
                PhoneNumber = model.Phone,
                Email = model.Email,
                Address = model.Address,
                LockoutEnabled = true,
                LockoutEnd = DateTime.Now.AddYears(10)
            };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var result1 = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Customer");
                return "Ok";
            }
            else
            {
                if (result.Errors.First().Code.Equals("PasswordRequiresLower"))
                {
                    message.ErrorMsg = "La clave debe contener al menos una letra.";
                    return "Clave incorrecta";
                }
                message.ErrorMsg = "El email ingresado ya esta registrado en el sistema.";
                return "Email incorrecto";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return "Error";
        }
    }


public string LogInUser(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (_userDataAccess.Exist(model.Username))
        {
            User user = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Username).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            if (user == null)
                user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            if (!user.LockoutEnabled && user.AccessFailedCount < 10)
            {
                _userManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                _userManager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user, false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                _userManager.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(user, DateTime.Now.AddDays(365)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            else if (user.LockoutEnabled)
            {
                return "Su cuenta esta desactivada.";
            }

            var result = _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, true, lockoutOnFailure: true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            if (!_userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
            {
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    if (user.AccessFailedCount > 0)
                    {
                        _userManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                        _userManager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user, false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    }
                    return "Ok";
                }
                else if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    return "Su cuenta esta desactivada.";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Incorrecto";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "El usuario no ha confirmado la cuenta";
            }
        }
        else
            return "El nombre de usuario es incorrecto";
    }
```

**ArticuloController**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
        // user queda en null

        List<Articulo> list = _articuloDataAccess.GetAll();
        return View(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me estaba faltando en el `startup.cs`. antes de `app.useMvc()`, agregar la línea `app.UseAuthentication()`